# Error No Runner was specified and the DirectRunner was not found on the classpath

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-cep

I am running a word count example on single node flink cluster running flink 1.6.1

and keep getting this error.

I am using beam version 2.8.0.

ERROR

```
jobmanager_1   | 2018-10-28 07:20:41,401 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler    - Exception occurred in REST handler.
jobmanager_1   | org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$handleRequest$7(JarRunHandler.java:151)
jobmanager_1   |    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
jobmanager_1   |    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
jobmanager_1   |    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
jobmanager_1   |    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1595)
jobmanager_1   |    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
jobmanager_1   |    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
jobmanager_1   |    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
jobmanager_1   |    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
jobmanager_1   |    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
jobmanager_1   |    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
jobmanager_1   | Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$getJobGraphAsync$10(JarRunHandler.java:228)
jobmanager_1   |    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
jobmanager_1   |    ... 6 more
jobmanager_1   | Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:546)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getOptimizedPlan(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:83)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:74)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$getJobGraphAsync$10(JarRunHandler.java:226)
jobmanager_1   |    ... 7 more
jobmanager_1   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Runner was specified and the DirectRunner was not found on the classpath.
jobmanager_1   | Specify a runner by either:
jobmanager_1   |     Explicitly specifying a runner by providing the 'runner' property
jobmanager_1   |     Adding the DirectRunner to the classpath
jobmanager_1   |     Calling 'PipelineOptions.setRunner(PipelineRunner)' directly
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions$DirectRunner.create(PipelineOptions.java:300)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions$DirectRunner.create(PipelineOptions.java:286)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:592)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:533)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:158)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsValidator.validate(PipelineOptionsValidator.java:97)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsValidator.validate(PipelineOptionsValidator.java:47)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:44)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:145)
jobmanager_1   |    at com.rnd.beam.PipelineDataHandler.runPipeline(PipelineDataHandler.java:75)
jobmanager_1   |    at com.rnd.beam.PipelineDataHandler.main(PipelineDataHandler.java:29)
jobmanager_1   |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jobmanager_1   |    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jobmanager_1   |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jobmanager_1   |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
jobmanager_1   |    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
jobmanager_1   |    ... 11 more
```

main class
`

```
public class PipelineDataHandler {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        counter.inc();
        p.apply(Create.of(LINES)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .apply(
                        FlatMapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                                .via((String word) -> Arrays.asList(word.split("[^\\p{L}]+"))))
                // We use a Filter transform to avoid empty word
                .apply(Filter.by((String word) -> !word.isEmpty()))
                .apply(Count.perElement())
                .apply(
                        MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                                .via(
                                        (KV<String, Long> wordCount) ->
                                                wordCount.getKey() + ": " + wordCount.getValue()))
                .apply(TextIO.write().to("wordcounts"));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
  }
}
```

`

gradle file

`

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

mainClassName = 'com.rnd.beam.PipelineDataHandler' //com/rnd/beam/PipelineDataHandler
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.8.0')
    compile('org.apache.beam:beam-runners-flink_2.11:2.8.0')
//    testCompile('org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.8.0')
    testCompile('org.testng:testng:6.14.+')
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'com.rnd.beam.PipelineDataHandler'
        )
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the runner in pipleline.There are two way to set it,one way is using the `pipeline.setRunner()` method to set the Beam Runner you want to use, the other way is to specify the Beam runner in command line,Example:

```
java -jar your_application.jar --runner=FlinkRunner
```

your code should look like this :

```
public class PipelineDataHandler {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
    p.setRunner(FlinkRunner.class)
    counter.inc();
    p.apply(Create.of(LINES)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
        .apply(
                FlatMapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                        .via((String word) -> Arrays.asList(word.split("[^\\p{L}]+"))))
        // We use a Filter transform to avoid empty word
        .apply(Filter.by((String word) -> !word.isEmpty()))
        .apply(Count.perElement())
        .apply(
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                        .via(
                                (KV<String, Long> wordCount) ->
                                        wordCount.getKey() + ": " + wordCount.getValue()))
        .apply(TextIO.write().to("wordcounts"));
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();}}
```

Comment: You must specify the runner in pipleline.There are two way to set it,one way is using the pipeline.setRunner() method to set the Beam Runner you want to use, the other way is to specify the Beam runner in command line,Example ：java -jar your_application.jar --runner=FlinkRunner